# Electron server-side using express

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm trying to create a server-side in electron in order to maintain the inputs.

Here is my script that I get inputs and send it to db ;

```
$("#confirm").click(function () {
            $.post("/addcustomerpost",
                { 
                    opcode: document.querySelector('#opcode').value,
                    cusname: document.querySelector('#cusname').value,
                },
                    function (data, status) {
                      if(data[0].code_received == "" || data[0].cusname_received == "") { 

                    $(".alert").remove();
                    var errorMessage = $('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert"                      style="font-size: 25px;">CANNOT BE EMPTY!</div>');

                    
                    errorMessage.css({
                        position: "fixed",
                        top: 10,
                        right: 690,
                        width: "20%",
                        "z-index": 9999,
                    });

                    
                    $("body").append(errorMessage);

                    
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        errorMessage.remove();
                    }, 3000); 
                            
                        }
                        else {
                        if(status === "success") alert("INFORMATION SAVED!");
                        else  alert("ERROR OCCURRED!");
                        }
                        
                    });
        });
```

It needs to access the **appExpress.post("/addcustomerpost",...)** , and here is the main.js ;

```
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const express = require('express');
const appExpress = express();
appExpress.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const port = 5500;

process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
appExpress.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/images'));


appExpress.use(express.static('/'));
appExpress.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

const path = require('path');

appExpress.post("/addcustomerpost",(req,res) => {

    if(req.body.opcode == "" || req.body.cusname == "") {
      console.log("not valid customer"); 
      res.json([{ 
        code_received: req.body.opcode,
        cusname_received: req.body.cusname,
      }]); 
    
    }
    else {
    res.json([{  // Just an response
      code_received: req.body.opcode,
      cusname_received: req.body.cusname,
    }]); 
    console.log("test_log"); //db operations will be here
    }
    
    });


let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {

    // start express server
    const server = appExpress.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
      });

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('entry.html');


 
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

 
});


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

However, when I submit the inputs it says ;  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /C:/addcustomerpost:1

Can you help me ?

I mean, I can do it in my web application nodejs, but couldn't manage it in electron.

Comment: You are requesting to `/addcustomerpost` end-point, can you try requesting to URL with protocol and domain like `http://localhost:3000/addcustomerpost`? I'm guessing, since electron app is just a desktop app, it may not have a root url defined to determine the relative path `/addcustomerpost`.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm adding this comment as an answer feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting to `/addcustomerpost` which is a relative path to your root URL.

Since electron apps are desktop apps, they don't have a defined root path for use of relative paths like in web applications. For that reason, your application is tryign to reach a path `C:/addcustomerpost` which is file system path.

To solve this problem, you need to specify protocol and domain in your URL as in the following format: `http://domain:port/addcustomerpost`. If you are working on a local environment then the URL will be `http://localhost:port/addcustomerpost`